# retrieve auto increment id for a different page

Tags: php, mysql

I have a two tables with an auto_incrementing id

```
MAINTENANCE
maintenance_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
description varchar(50)
PRIMARY KEY (maintenance_id)
```

I have a query on my maintenance.php page that generates the maintenance_id.

```
$sql = "insert into maintenancereq (maintenance_id,description)
        values('','description')";
```

And I have a different php page where I need that maintenance_id. How would I go about finding what ID was generated on the maintenance.php page for a different query on a different page?

Answer (score 1):

Through a way to manatain persistent data:

1. You could use sessions `$_SESSION`, to have persistent data in next page
2. You could redirect from `maintenance.php` to next page with an id in link, your link could look something like `http://myurl?maintenanceId=1&blah=blah`.

Then will get the id through `$_GET`

```
if( isset($_GET['maintenanceId']) && is_numeric($_GET['maintenanceId']) ) {
 // do blah blah
}
```

Comment: Use `mysql_insert_id()` only if you are sure that the current client, will not insert new data into `maintenancereq `

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to use

```
mysql_insert_id();
```

in your code.
This retrieves the ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query (usually INSERT).

```
$sql = "insert into maintenancereq (maintenance_id,description)
        values('','description')";
```

Just execute the above query and use mysql_insert_id();. You can put this value on the url string and get the value from the next page. Alternatively you can put it to session and then retrieve it from session.

Do have a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL provides the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function for such cases.

Execute

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

after having inserted a row and the result will be the auto-generated ID. Note that this query should be executed directly after the insertion as the same connection has to be used. The retrieved value would then have to be passed to another page, e.g. via parameters or session variables. If the same connection is used, another `INSERT` into the same table by another client is not problematic, as the documentation states:

> Each client will receive the last inserted ID for the last statement that client executed

For more information, see the [MySQL Documentation about that function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html)

Comment: Will this work even if the query is on a different php file to where the original query was executed?

Comment: Yes, but in another page when he get's the last_insert_id, and exist  risk that other script's to use that table and insert data. If this happens he will not get the real last_insert_id

Comment: Agree, the query for the last insert ID would have to be executed directly after the `INSERT`. Then, it happens on the same connection. The id value would then have to be passed to other pages, e.g. via sessions or params.